# Convert numpy pixel matrix to OpenCv image

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert a numpy array(shape: 48,48) containing a grayscale image to a Cv Mat or Img object.

I've already tried the cv2.imdecode function but it just returned an empty matrix as described in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html) but it doesn't tell me why it's not working.

```py
    data = prep_data()

    img_raw = np.array(data[1][0])
    print(img_raw)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_raw, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the exception I get, but I've already "found out" that this exception is because the img obj is empty.
Exception:
`cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:325: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, OpenCV images are NumPy arrays.
So it dependes on what your *prep_data* function returns, but you probably don't need to call *cv2.imdecode*. What does *print(img_raw)* return in your code? Anyway, try showing directly img_raw:

```
data = prep_data()

img_raw = np.array(data[1][0])
cv2.imshow('image',img_raw)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```